# Controller variables are not recognizable in some views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, scope, redmine

How to pass variables between the application controller and different views in Ruby on rails ?  Is there any global scope which helps us to keep track of any variable created in the controller and use it in any   view code in the same application ?

Comment: What you try to achieve? Can you please add an example?

Comment: I'm actually working on a redmine plugin . I have my view file "_index.html.erb" in "myPlugin/app/views" . I couldn't use instance variables (declared in my application controller) from the "_index.html.erb" view file . The log file said that "@project" was not recognized ...  Despite that , I was able to interact with the same controller from another view in myPlugin/app/views/myPlugin/index.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

To use a method from the application controller in a view, mark it as an helper method.
Something like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  helper_method :current_user

end
```

Now, the `current_user` method is accessible in all views and it can be used to get the `@current_user` instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Write your code in application helper and it will be accessible through out any view in application..

Answer (score 0):

please read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html (Especially part 3)

This is not the best option though, I recommend reading about exposing you variables in controllers.

https://github.com/hashrocket/decent_exposure 
or
https://github.com/netguru/decent_decoration

are created just for that and I recommend them.

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared like so:

```
@current_user
```

for example will be available in any views as long as the method that creates that variable is called in the controller for that view.

You can read more about ruby variables here http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/variables.html